# ISS: Procedure in case of collision warning

Tags: iss, debris, soyuz-spacecraft, astronauts, conjunction

In case of collision warning occurring to the ISS, if ISS can't be moved the procedure is to go to a Soyuz and wait.

Can anyone gives details about the procedure? 
Is the Soyuz hermetically closed from the ISS? 
Do the crew have to put on the space suits? 
Is the Soyuz powered on and ready to go back to Earth?

Answer (score 2):

[Astrowatch](http://www.astrowatch.net/2015/07/space-station-crew-hides-from-space-junk.html) has the answer, which is:

> Per Flight Rule B4-101, a “late conjunction” call results in the crew being ordered to close the hatches between Station modules and enter the Soyuz vehicles – which serve as lifeboats during their docked stay at the ISS – before TCA (Time of Closest Approach) breaches the 10 minute mark.

It is my understanding that the hatchs are closed (From above), and the spacecraft is ready to depart on a moments notice using an emergency departure system.